# Why does lifetime coercion work with structs but not with traits?

Tags: struct, rust, traits, lifetime, coercion

The following code is not accepted by the compiler:

```
struct Struct<'a, 'b: 'a> {
    value: &'a dyn Value<'b>,
}

impl<'a, 'b: 'a> Struct<'a, 'b> {
    fn foo(&self) {
        UnitedLifetime(self.value);
    }
}

struct UnitedLifetime<'a>(&'a dyn Value<'a>);

trait Value<'a> {}
```

It produces the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for automatic coercion due to conflicting requirements
 --> src/lib.rs:7:24
  |
7 |         UnitedLifetime(self.value);
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
 --> src/lib.rs:5:6
  |
5 | impl<'a, 'b: 'a> Struct<'a, 'b> {
  |      ^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
 --> src/lib.rs:7:24
  |
7 |         UnitedLifetime(self.value);
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'b` as defined here...
 --> src/lib.rs:5:10
  |
5 | impl<'a, 'b: 'a> Struct<'a, 'b> {
  |          ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
 --> src/lib.rs:7:24
  |
7 |         UnitedLifetime(self.value);
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^
  = note: expected `dyn Value<'_>`
             found `dyn Value<'b>`
```

If I use `struct Value<'a>(&'a u8);` instead of traits, it compiles.

I want to have an `UnitedLifetime` that has a lifetime as long as `Struct`, which in turn has lifetimes for other objects, which means that `'a: '_` and `'b: '_` are always true.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a compiler bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is variance.

`dyn Trait<'b>` is invariant over `'b`. That means, in other words, that `'b` must be exactly `'b` and not any other lifetime, neither shorter nor longer. Thus, the compiler cannot use "the shorter of `'a` and `'b`".

[Trait objects are always invariant over their generic arguments](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/subtyping.html#variance).

`u8`, on the other hand, has no reference to `'b`. `&'a u8` is covariant over `'a`. That means that it can shrink, and thus the compiler can use "the shorter of".

You can see that variance is the problem and not the trait if you'll replace `dyn Value<'b>` with a struct that is invariant over `'b`:

```rust
struct Value<'a> {
    // `fn(&'a ()) -> &'a ()` is both covariant over `'a` (because of the parameter)
    // and contravariant over it (because of the return type). covariant+contravariant=invariant.
    _marker: PhantomData<fn(&'a ()) -> &'a ()>
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d3ae4344e65d6904777becf9bf9a74fd).

---

To explain *why* trait objects are invariant over their parameters, inspect the following example:

```rust
trait Value<'a> {
    fn set_value(&mut self, v: &'a i32);
}

struct S<'a> {
    value: Box<&'a i32>,
}

impl<'a> Value<'a> for S<'a> {
    fn set_value(&mut self, v: &'a i32) {
        *self.value = v;
    }
}

fn foo<'a>(v: &mut dyn Value<'a>) {
    let new_value: i32 = 0;
    let new_value_ref: &i32 = &new_value;
    v.set_value(new_value_ref);
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = S { value: Box::new(&0) };
    foo(&mut s);
    dbg!(&**s.value);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0f8eb19f7bfb0d39956ddedd98220d34).

If trait objects were covariant over their parameters, `foo()` would compile. We only shrink the lifetime - from `'a` to the lifetime of the local variable `new_value`, which is always shorter.

But this would be terrible, since after exiting `foo()`, `new_value` would be destroyed, and `s.value` would point to freed memory - use-after-free!

This is why mutable references are invariant. But trait objects can contain *anything* - including mutable references - so any parameter of them has to be invariant!

**Note:** I wasn't accurate when saying that if we would be covariant over `'a` we will compile, because we still take `&mut self` and thus invariant over `S<'a>` and, transitively, over `'a`. But we can adjust this example to use interior mutability and take `&self` which is covariant. I did not do that in order to not complicate things more.

Comment: I initially also thought that this is a variance issue. But at this point I'm pretty sure it is another implied bounds issue. As you point out, lifetimes are invariant for mutable lifetimes. But this is not the case for immutable lifetimes, which should be covariant. I have opened two issues in the Rust tracker that are - unlike this one - pretty clearly bugs. If they ever fix those, I will just nag them with this one :).

However I'm still grateful for your comment and I gave you an up-vote.

Comment: Like a said, in trait objects everything is invariant. This is because they _can_ contain mutable references, and the compiler has no way of knowing about that. This is referred to explicitly in the reference, as I pointed out.

Comment: I don't see that documented. It's documented that in `Trait<T> + 'a` T is invariant and 'a is covariant. Also I feel like it's wrong to say that an immutable trait reference has access to mutable references. Of course you can have a &mut in a trait implementation, but that is never mutable if you only have a `&self`.

Comment: `&self` can be mutable with interior mutability. And the `T` in `dyn Trait<T>` is not necessarily a type - it can also be a lifetime.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3301fd96c1ce4a148b210cbd818bb617) that would compile without this check and create a UAF vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks for the example! This means my biggest wish for Rust to make something like `covariant trait<'x>` possible, where the compiler ensures that all trait implementations are covariant and therefore its lifetimes are as well.

Comment: @DaveHalter Yeah, but I'd not expect Rust do have that. This is pretty nich, I think.

Comment: @DaveHalter More accurately, you need something like `trait Trait<covariant 'x>`. Java and C# has something similar.

Comment: @DaveHalter [Covariance and contravariance in generics - C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance), [Variance in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variance-in-java/).